# Launch docker container for each user

Tags: docker

So, I have this application as a service. Each application is user specific. So for each user, I would like to launch a new docker instance. There should be a possibility to restart the docker instance where it was last left. So it needs persistent storage too.

I would like to know if there are any library/framework which makes this easier? Would be great if this library is golang library.

Hint1: It is not the same, but similar to how services like koding.com, etc launch a separate container for each user/user's project.

Comment: How about using a network storage for the persistent data?

Comment: Persistent data in itself is not the problem. This library should map this persistent data to a user and mount it to the newly launched docker depending on the user. It is not difficult. But wondering if there is a framework already present that i can use or at least look at the architecture and imitate.

Comment: I think this kind of services are the future of the Cloud. Wondering why there are no open source libraries available.

I am pro cloud. So i am converting all my applications to Cloud. But some of them are not generic service. What I mean generic is for example an MMORPG game or mail client. They may have one instance running and user/instance is abstracted by database.

What if, a running instance can run for only one user. For example, an IDE or a simulator.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [Giant Swarm](https://docs.giantswarm.io/fundamentals/introduction/). It let's you build, deploy and manage your containerized server applications(microservices). But I think it's in a closed beta now.

> Services you run on Giant Swarm are defined in a service definition
>   file. In this definition you assemble any number of Docker images,
>   each forming a component, according to your needs. To deploy a
>   service, first, you use a Docker client or a CI/CD pipeline to create
>   and deploy Docker images. Then you use Giant Swarm’s client software
>   or our API to start the creation and orchestration of your Docker
>   containers on the cluster, based on your service defintition and
>   images.